# Primer Design with Primer-BLAST over specific site

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, blast, primer

I am trying to design primers using Primer-BLAST such that the forward primer spans a specific base pair site.

I am looking at KRAS for which I believe the **RefSeq ID** is **NG_007524.1** and the forward primer should span **chr12:25398285**.

However, I'm not sure how to restrict the design to accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to amplify the genomic DNA or mRNA?

Comment: I want to amplify DNA.

Comment: In any case, I always verify the primers on the UCSC In-Silico PCR tool (https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgPcr). You can never make sure enough with genomic DNA...

Answer (score 2):

I think various ways can be apply, but the easiest way could be to indicate the range to set a forward primer.

Decide the length of primer you are going to get.

Let's say you would like 25 mer.

You can set the range from **chr12:25398261** to **chr12:25398309**.

When you identify where **chr12:25398285** is in **NG_007524.1**, you are ready to design your primers.

Comment: If he had to sequence _KRAS_ gene, he had to amplify fragments of a determined maximum lenght, depending of the platform used. Also, do not forget that many sequencers need some bases (20-40) to warm up, and some other to land. E.G. I want to sequence a fragment from bp 100 to 150 of a given gene: I will design primers starting from bp 50-70 and stop at about 170. Personally I design primers pairs for any coding exon of a gene.